why cant we have a parameterized constructor of parent class when no value is being passed in the child class?
class a{
    a(int age){}
}
class b extends a{}
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b var1=new b();
        System.out.println("Try programiz.pro");
    }
}

above code doesnt work.if i include the statement super(10) in child class constructor, it works.
but without any constructor in a ,it works like below
class a{}
class b extends a{}
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        b var1=new b();
        System.out.println("Try programiz.pro");
    }
}

if that is because we are required to give default constructor of super class in 2nd code we havent specified the constructor and still it works.can you explain why?

In Java, the compiler inserts a default constructor if and only if no explicit constructor has been defined for the class1. This default constructor:

Has zero parameters.
Has the same visibility as the class
Invokes the superclass's zero-parameter constructor2.

That last bit is why your first code example fails to compile. Your A class has defined an explicit constructor which has one parameter, thus it does not have a zero-parameter constructor to invoke from the default constructor of subclass B.

First case
When you have:
public class A {

  // Explicit constructor
  public A(int arg) {}
}

public class B extends A {}

That is the same as writing:
public class A extends Object {

  // Note: No default constructor.

  // Explicit constructor
  public A(int arg) {
      super(); // OKAY: The 'Object' class has a no-arg constructor.
  }
}

public class B extends A {

  // Default constructor
  public B() {
      super(); // ERROR: The 'A' class does not have a no-arg constructor.
  }
}

Second case
When you have:
public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

That is the same as writing:
public class A extends Object {

  // Default constructor
  public A() {
    super(); // OKAY: The 'Object' class has a no-arg constructor.
  }
}

public class B extends A {

  // Default constructor
  public B() {
    super(); // OKAY: The 'A' class has a no-arg constructor.
  }
}


1. See §8.8.7. Constructor Body and §8.8.9. Default Constructor of the Java Language Specification.
2. Note every constructor has an implicit call to super() unless there is an explicit call to a super constructor or an explicit delegation to another constructor in the same class (i.e., this(...)). See §8.8.7. Constructor Body of the Java Language Specification.

why cant java insert a no arg constructor in a in first case?

Constructors are meant to initialize a class to a well-defined state. You've given A an explicit constructor that accepts an int as an argument. Clearly, that int is important to the initialization logic. So, how should the compiler implement a default constructor in that case? It has no idea what that argument is for or which value it should pass. The developer wrote an explicit constructor with arguments for a reason; if a no-argument constructor should exist alongside the parameterized constructor(s) then it is left to the developer to write one. It's safer that way.

Note this behavior is defined by the Java Language Specification. I've added links to my answer.

Java can't insert it because the JLS says so.  This is how Java was specified ... back in the 1990's ... and the designers (presumably) have not seen or heard a compelling reason to change this.  And I can't think of a good (let alone compelling) reason to change it either.  And there are good reasons NOT to do it ... to do with abstraction boundaries.

The first line in a subclass constructor must be the invocation of a superclass constructor. If a subclass constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically includes a call to the zero-arguments constructor of the superclass. If there is no such constructor, it results in a compile-time error. Which is exactly what you describe and what happens with code like in your example.
Read this for more information on super() and subclass constructors.
